# How to check if submitted element value already exists?

Tags: php, xml

So, as for an assignment I'm coding a PHP versed page that allows you to submit order id's to an XML  config, so it filters desired orders out.

All works fine and great, but I want to alert the user the moment the submitted ID already exists in the config.

XML elements

```
<filter><!-- Copy filter-item and put the order-id in as the value to skip it-->
<filter_item>1142575860</filter_item><filter_item>1142495027</filter_item>
</filter>
```

```
    if (isset($_POST['btnAddId'])) 
{
    $addID = $_POST['idFilter'];
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('Config.xml');

    if(empty($addID)) 
    {
        echo '<script> alert("Input value is empty");</script>';
    }
    else if(!is_numeric($addID)) 
    {
        echo '<script> alert("input is not numeric");</script>';
    }
    else if(??)
    {
        echo '<script> alert("ID already exists in the filter");</script>';
    }
    else{    
        
        $orderFilter = $_POST['idFilter'];
        $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());
    
        $itemsNode = $sxe->filter;
    
        $itemsNode->addChild('filter_item', $orderFilter);
        $sxe->asXML('Config.xml');
        
        echo $LocScript; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath to search for a `<filter_item>` element which has the same content as the ID they have entered...

```
if ( count($xml->xpath('//filter_item[.="'.$addID.'"]')) > 0 )
{
   echo '<script> alert("ID already exists in the filter");</script>';
}
```

Which gives an XPath expression of (for example)

```
//filter_item[.="1142495027"]
```

as this matches one of the items, it will return a list containing 1 item.  The condition with `count()` will then trigger that an item already exists.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I had a hunch I had to use XPath for this, but made the mistake to throw a query in it, since I use it to pick out specific IDs to remove them from the config.